# Issues with importing win32gui python 3.9

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I'm trying to use win32gui from pywin32 but I keep getting this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'

I am on windows 10, python 3.9

I have been researching the top results on stack over flow and google for a while now and the solutions i found don't work for me.

things I have tried:

- installed pywin32 via a whl file (this shows in site packages along with win32 ect)
- double checked both 64bit versions of python and pywin32 are installed
- Added pywin32 to Path (worth a try)
- tried "from win32 import win32gui"

Any help would be appreciated!

**Requested commands with output:**

importing win32api and win32com results in the same out of

- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

python -m pip install pywin32
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (304.0)

python -c "import win32gui" -- nothing happens when i run this line in a cmd (maybe i have done something wrong here?)

Comment: Do other modules work (`import win32api`, `import win32com`? )Please add some commands and their outputs: what I'm interested in is `python -m pip install pywin32`, followed by `python -c "import win32gui"`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have added the information you requested (hopefully correctly)

Comment: If nothing happens, then the import must have been successful.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, i just got back to it today and the issue still persists. I have simply started a new virtual env and begun again however this time it seems to have worked. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution unknown however it was fixed by simply recreating the virtual environment and installing the pywin32.